# Hölder estimate of solution to linear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

Consider a standard Cauchy-Dirichlet problem for linear parabolic PDE:
\begin{cases}
u_t + \mathcal{L}u=-g, \ (t,x) \in [0,T)\times \Omega \\ 
u(T,x)=0 , \ x\in \Omega\\ 
u|_{\partial \Omega}=0 
\end{cases}
Under nice assumptions on $\mathcal{L}$, $g$ and $\partial \Omega$, we have the well known (boundary) Schauder estimate:
$$\exists C>0, \  |u|_{2+ \alpha} \leq C|g|_{\alpha},$$ where for $0<\alpha<1$, $|g|_{\alpha}$ denotes the $\alpha$-Hölder norm of $g$:
$$|g|_{\alpha} := \sup_{(t,x)}|g(t,x)| + \sup_{\substack{(t,x)\\(\tilde{t},\tilde{x})}}\dfrac{|g(t,x)-g(\tilde{t},\tilde{x})|}{\sqrt{|x-\tilde{x}|^2  + |t-\tilde{t}|}^{\ \alpha}},
$$ 
and
$$|u|_{2+\alpha}:=|u|_{\alpha}+\sum|D_x u|_{\alpha}+\sum|D_x ^2 u|_{\alpha}+|D_t u|_{\alpha}.
$$
The above estimate essential says that the $(2+\alpha)$ norm of the solution can be bounded by the $\alpha$-norm of $g$. However in my current application, I only need a bound on the $\alpha$-norm of the solution, but in terms of the infinity norm of $g$, i.e. something like:
$$|u|_{\alpha} \leq C \cdot \sup_{(t,x)}|g(t,x)|.$$
My question is: is there a standard reference to this type of Hölder estimate of solution to linear parabolic PDEs? Thank you very much!